# TextExt Plugin: подключение

Tags: jquery

Прошу прощения за оффтопик - но есть проблема в подключении плагина [TextExt Plugin](http://textextjs.com/).
В доке написано, что нужно подключить необходимые js скрипты на страницу и указать это в параметрах функции-инициализации.
Но при этом ничего не срабатывает, ошибок не выдает, версию jquery менять тоже пробовал - не помогло

Comment: никаких проблем http://plnkr.co/edit/5Lj7yqHcGriYFQIWCM41?p=preview

Comment: спасибо - этот вопрос решил. остался вопрос как сохранять id выбранных элементов из подгружаемого списка? чтобы потом занести в БД